# How to format enterprise number for Belgium businesses?

Tags: validation-rule, inputfield

How can I put in place a control on an "Enterprise number" (basically the national ID for businesses) field to respect the format enforced by Belgium fiscal law?

Answer (score 0):

Using the following link which explains the format control:
https://gathering.tweakers.net/forum/list_messages/1059487

I have created the following validation rule, enforced on a text field of length 10. The field name is Enterprise_number__c and it seems to be working fine.

IF( 97-MOD(VALUE(LEFT( Enterprise_number__c ,8)),97)=VALUE(RIGHT( Enterprise_number__c ,2)),FALSE,TRUE)